# Wrong alignment after \multicolumn

Tags: tables

I used multicolumnn to get some text in 3 columns. The problem is that i can't get A, B, C and the numbers in the center of the column anymore.

What am i doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{array} % zorgt dat er een tabel gemaakt kan worden zoals auteur
\usepackage{booktabs} %multicolumn met array
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| m{9cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm} | m{3cm |}}
\multirow{4}{*}{Storing} & \multicolumn{3}{L{5.5cm}}{Kritische veranderingswaarde in procenten voor meters van klasse} \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\[2pt]
Omgekeerde fasevolgorde& \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1,5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,3} \\[2pt]
Spanning in onbalans & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! They seem to be centred, on your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{array} % zorgt dat er een tabel gemaakt kan worden zoals auteur
\usepackage{booktabs} %multicolumn met array
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| m{5cm} | C{3cm} | C{3cm} | C{3cm} |}
\multirow{4}{*}{Storing} & \multicolumn{3}{L{9cm}|}{Kritische veranderingswaarde in procenten voor meters van klasse} \\
 & A & B & C \\[2pt]
Omgekeerde fasevolgorde& 1,5 & 1,5 & 0,3 \\[2pt]
Spanning in onbalans & 4 & 2 & 1 \\[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have now removed all the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` from your MWE. Also added a new column specifier `C` and changed the width of first column to `5cm`.

Comment: This is definitely better, i only noticed one thing.

When i make the vertically space bigger, like 20 instead of 2 so you can see the difference, the C goes to the top.

    & A & B & C \\[20pt]
   
 
[Example](http://i.imgur.com/f9IRzVB.png)

Comment: So could you try changing the `m{#1}` to `p{#1}`in `\newcolumntype`.

Comment: That did the trick. But how come it only affects the C?